# Pop-ups in Chrome Cause Mountain Lion to Switch Spaces

Tags: macos, google-chrome, spaces

I have 5 spaces. I assigned Chrome to Space 2. When I encounter a pop-up in Chrome, Mountain Lion automatically switches to Space 3 and prevents me from switching back to Space 2. I'm forced to quit Chrome to make Space 2 useable again.

And then, when I restart Chrome, it appears on Space 5. Mountain Lion will not keep the applications on the spaces of which I assigned them to.

Has anyone else experienced these issues? Are there any fixes?

Comment: Can you clarify your question by adding wich version of Mac OS you are using ?

Comment: **Pop-ups in Chrome Cause Mountain Lion to Switch Spaces**... 

I'm running Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1):

This is also an issue that I have, whether a pop-up occurs or I open a new window in Chrome it switches to a non Chrome space on my machine. I am using 10.8.3 Mountain Lion OSx and can repro on another machine on the same build.

This leads me to think it's simply a bug and we'll need to wait for a better workaround or a fix from Apple and/or Chrome.